# PHP file does not return complete json data

Tags: php, json

I am making a php file which will return json data to javascript file. Currently it only returns the last json object and ignores the rest of them. Here is my php code

```
$arr = array(
  "cartId" => 456186,
  "lastModified" => "Tue, 19 Jan 2010 03:14:07 GMT",
  "items" => array(
    15642,
    45616,
    54984,
    45751
  ),
  "cartId" => 456187,
  "lastModified" => "Tue, 20 Jan 2010 04:14:07 GMT",
  "items" => array(
    'item' => 15643,
    'item' => 45617,
    'item' => 54985,
    'item' => 45752
  )
);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

above code returns following

```
{"cartId":456187,"lastModified":"Tue, 20 Jan 2010 04:14:07 GMT","items":{"item":45752}}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: An array cannot have duplicate keys, and neither can a JSON object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first elements are being overwritten with the second elements as their keys are same. Same with the `items` array in the second item.

Try

```
$arr = array (
  array(
    "cartId"       => 456186,
    "lastModified" => "Tue, 19 Jan 2010 03:14:07 GMT",
    "items"        => array(
      15642,
      45616,
      54984,
      45751, 
    ),
  ),
  array(
    "cartId"       => 456187,
    "lastModified" => "Tue, 20 Jan 2010 04:14:07 GMT",
    "items"        => array(
      15643,
      45617,
      54985,
      45752, 
    ),
  ), 
);
```

Comment: Error corrected. Please use a decent editor with syntax highlighting to write code.

Comment: This does not return all of the `'item'`. It just return last item

Comment: Even if it was meant to be a linked list, the last array still doesn't have a key (it does have a key assigned, but still...) .

Comment: @MadaraUchiha It seemed too easy and so I tried to fix it from the SO editor itself. Lesson learnt.

Comment: now it's syntax error again, unless the comma operator works in PHP (in which case it still discards everything but the last record)

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
$arr = array(
  array(
    "cartId" => 456186,
    "lastModified" => "Tue, 19 Jan 2010 03:14:07 GMT",
    "items" => array(
      15642,
      45616,
      54984,
      45751
    )
  ),
  array(
    "cartId" => 456187,
    "lastModified" => "Tue, 20 Jan 2010 04:14:07 GMT",
    "items" => array(
      15643,
      45617,
      54985,
      45752
    )
  )
);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

The reason for your error is because you can't have duplicate keys in a PHP array (or a JSON object for that matter). The later keys overrode the former, and a smaller version of the array was created.

Here, we are grouping the items into sub-arrays.

Comment: This still overwrites each previous item in the second items array

Comment: @pburgess Have you tried running this solution? It works as expected. It produces both objects correctly

Comment: @pankar Are you sure? It depends what "expected" is. That second array still overwrites each previous key in the "items" array. If that is expected behavior then I believe it works as expected, otherwise it does not. I still believe this returns a second object with "items":{"item":45752} in the json encoded string, rather than each element.

Comment: This is the output of this code running:

[{"cartId":456186,"lastModified":"Tue, 19 Jan 2010 03:14:07 GMT","items":[15642,45616,54984,45751]},{"cartId":456187,"lastModified":"Tue, 20 Jan 2010 04:14:07 GMT","items":{"item":45752}}]

Comment: That output is what I would expect, I do not believe it is the intended output, but that is for the poster of the question to decide!

Comment: I edited my answer to fix the issue with the 'items' overwriting each other in the second array.  This should possibly fix the issue the poster was having.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot give same index

```
$arr = array(
      "cartId1" => 456186,
      "lastModified1" => "Tue, 19 Jan 2010 03:14:07 GMT",
      "items1" => array(
        15642,
        45616,
        54984,
        45751
      ),
      "cartId2" => 456187,
      "lastModified2" => "Tue, 20 Jan 2010 04:14:07 GMT",
      "items2" => array(
        'items1' => 15643,
        'items2' => 45617,
        'items3' => 54985,
        'items4' => 45752
      )
    );
    echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: overwrites `cartId` and `lastModified`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you basically need to do:

```
$arr = array(
        array(
            "cartId" => 456186,
            "lastModified" => "Tue, 19 Jan 2010 03:14:07 GMT",
            "items" => array(
                15642,
                45616,
                54984,
                45751
            ),
        ),
        array(
           "cartId" => 456187,
            "lastModified" => "Tue, 20 Jan 2010 04:14:07 GMT",
            "items" => array(
                'item' => 15643,
                'item' => 45617,
                'item' => 54985,
                'item' => 45752
            ) 
        )
    );
```

So as you can see we are having to wrap the collection of nested elements inside of array's.

Answer (score 0):

You're not properly setting up a multidimensional array.

To do that you need to use `array()` to set up the nested / inner arrays.

`$arr = array(array("key"=>"value"), array("key"=>"value"));`

rather than what you're currently doing:

`$arr = array(("key"=>"value"), ("key"=>"value"));`